# getBit function not giving correct result

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bit

The following getBit function in Python is to get True if a bit is set at index i and False if it is 0.

```
def getBit(num, i):
    return ((num & (1 << i)) != 0)
```

For the following testcases, I get the output as below:

```
print(getBit(1011, 2))
print(getBit(1011, 1))
print(getBit(11011, 3))
print(getBit(1011, 3))

False
True
False
False
```

The first 2 output are correct but the last 2 are wrong. What is wrong with the code? (1 << 3) does give 8 but on and with 1011 it does not give 1 as there is in the 3rd position.

Comment: They appear to be right, when I print those numbers in binary. Are you wanting the inputs to be in base2 instead of base10 like they are?

Comment: yes, i do want it in base2, should I just use bin()

Comment: isn't it easier to do this `return str(num)[i] == '1'`?

Comment: print (getBit(0b1011, 3))

Comment: @Marcos not using that because index out of range gives False i.e. 0 directly eg. getBit(0b1011, 4), so we don't need to handle that using masking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test cases are incorrect. You are taking the third bit of 1011, which would be expressed in binary as 0b1111110011. As you can see, the third bit is 0.

```
def getBit(num, i):
    print ("{0:b}".format(num))
    binary_positional_value = (num & (1 << i))
    return binary_positional_value != 0

print(getBit(1011, 3))
```

> 1111110011
>   False

But you were thinking that 1011 was the binary representation. That would be done like so:

```
print(getBit(0b1011, 3))
```